# creating new cookie when user logout in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using spring security for authentication and in my current implementation when the user logs out, I am invalidating the session and deleting the cookie

what I am looking for is to add a fresh cookie along with old cookie value deletion.

I also happen to see that the cookie is added only once the user is authenticated. Is it possible to add cookies soon after the first page is requested?

Thanks

Comment: Which cookie? Why would you need a new session cookie if there is no session?

Comment: I needed to use it for containerisation, as the service is replicated to 2 pod(s) the request can go to any pod. in ingress sessionAffinity is based on cookie. which was missing before when user is UnAuthorised.

Fixed it by changing sesssionCreationPolicy to `sesssionCreationPolicy(ALWAYS)`

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it by changing `sesssionCreationPolicy to sesssionCreationPolicy(ALWAYS)`